# AJAX Not returning

Tags: ajax

```
            alert("orger");

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "localhost:8080/greeting",
                success: function(data) {
                     alert("hello");
                }
             });
```

The browser outputs "orger", but not "hello". What is the issue? When I invoke the url in the browser, the page renders successfully.

Comment: u r not sending data in ajax request so that might be the problem

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

The **jqXHR.success()**, **jqXHR.error()**, and **jqXHR.complete()** callbacks are deprecated as of **jQuery 1.8**. , use **jqXHR.done()**, **jqXHR.fail()**, and **jqXHR.always()** instead.

Answer (score 0):

too many possibilities for Ajax not returning.
- It might be jQuery not plugged
- url not found.
- HttpService got error, so it goes in error part.
- etc.

so look at the below link, i will help you.
[enter link description here](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)